# R - JSON Returned from RCurl::getURL has Special Characters that make it invalid with fromJSON

Tags: json, r, curl, geturl, rjsonio

How can make sure that the result of my `getURL()` call is properly formatted to be parsed using from JSON?

---

**Details**

If I take the string for api URL and paste that into Chrome, then copy and paste out the resulting JSON, `RJSONIO::fromJSON()` will parse it.  However, if I pass the variable test, as in my code below, to `fromJSON()`, I get this error:

> Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
>     invalid JSON input

In going through the differences between the two, I found some issues encoding escaped character sequences such as `"\\\"\\\\\\\""` which I am able to search for and replace. However there are some other things, where for example, the broken JSON will show `" "` while the working JSON will show "\u00A0".

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)

apiURL= #sorry I can't post the actual URL due to company security policies
test<-getURL(apiURL,userpwd="myusername:mypassword",httpauth=1L)
transcripts1 <- fromJSON(test)
```

Comment: Check out utils::URLencode

Comment: `"\\"\\\\""` is not a legitimate R character value. The first backslash escapes the second backslash, so the second double quote terminates the strings, making the rest of the string "not there" but also an error.

Comment: Can you post a demo url and paste the values of test. Some sample will be good to work with.

Comment: @chinsoon12 : I just tried URLencode() on my JSON text, but it still failed when trying to parse it after

Comment: @42- : The plaintext is "doublequote backslash doublequote". "\\\"\\\\\\\"" is the expression that I need to find/replace using gsub.

Comment: @Tushar : As mentioned above, I cannot post the URL or sample JSON.  However, the same URL generates working JSON text in chrome, but does not work with getURL.  My question is how I can get the result of the API call to provide working JSON text in R, while I already know that that the URL provides functional JSON in chrome.

Comment: did you try
test<-getURL(utils::URLencode(apiURL),userpwd="myusername:mypassword",httpauth=1L) and also try fromJSON(URLencode(test))